# Base DB schema didn't create table

Tags: magento2, exception, table, whitelist, db-schema

In my report_sales > coupons page I get exception

`Base table or view not found: 1146 Table salesrule_coupon_aggregated doesn't exist`

And I find out that system didn't create this table (It doesn't exist in my database).

What is the right way to create this table. Re run setup/upgrade or I need delete whitelist and than re-generate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the following commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```